# How to mock a class call in Python?

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to test a function which contain a class call, like this :

```
    def products_list_creator(self, category, number_of_pages):
        products_list = []
        api_request = dict(requests.get(f"https://fr-en.openfoodfacts.org/category/{category}/{number_of_pages}.json").json())
        for json_product in api_request["products"]:
            product = ApiProduct(json_product)
            print(product)
            if self.product_data_validity(product):
                products_list.append(product)
        return products_list
```

So I tried to mock it in my test.py like this :

```
    @patch('requests.get')
    def test_products_list_creator(self, mock_get):
                
        test_json_product = dumps({"products":
            [
                {
                    "name": "apple",
                },
                {
                    "name": "banana",
                }
            ]
        }).encode('ascii')

        resp = Response()
        resp.encoding = 'ascii'
        resp._content = test_json_product

        mock_get.return_value = resp

        _product_maker.ApiProduct = MagicMock(return_value="product")
        
        self.command.product_data_validity = MagicMock(return_value=True)
        
        response = self.command.products_list_creator(None,None)
        assert [["product"],["product"]] == [response]
```

This doesn't worked so I decided to add a print in my function to know what is the value of product when I test and I got this response :
`<main_site.management.commands._product_maker.ApiProduct object at 0x058C8190>`

Here is my ApiProduct :

```
class ApiProduct:
    """This class create a product"""

    def __init__(self, json_product):
        self.json_product = json_product

    def name(self):
        """Search for name"""
        try:
            if self.json_product["product_name"] != "":
                return self.json_product["product_name"]
            else:
                return None
        except KeyError:
            print("Name not found")
            return None
```

So how to mock a class ?

Comment: Does your function have a `return` - i.e., `return return_value`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris Sorry i don't get it. What do you want me to try ?

Comment: Does your class `ApiProduct` have a return in `__init__`?

Comment: No, but I have many function in it returning values.

Comment: We will need to see the actual code in order to help.

Comment: when you do `product = ApiProduct(json_product)` You are just creating the object you are not retuning anything  because only the `__init__` runs. Did you mean to call the `name` method, which does have a `return`? `product = ApiProduct(json_product).name()`

Comment: No, I do this later in the code. In this function i just take the products instances and put them in a list.

Comment: Its one of my first codes I had to unburry for a school project, I know its not the best at all but it work and in 2 weeks it will be in the bin so I dont want to change everything now. Is there no way to test it ? I dont need a 100% coverage so I can pass it if its untestable